# How to detect the type of a column in a numpy matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a training dataset that I converted into a `numpy` matrix in order to train a classifier. However before doing that I need to do some preprocessing on the matrix. In the matrix each row represents an instance/record and each column is an attribute. For each type of attribute I need to do a specific preprocessing, i.e real-value attribute/column has a different preprocessing than a column that has only binary values.

These are the preprocessing steps that I want to do:

For columns that have only real-values:

- Make 10 bins/intervals (0.0, 0.1), (0.1, 0.2), (0.2, 0.3), (0.3,0.4), ..., (0.9, 1.0). Then find the **indices** of the rows that fall within the first bin, the second bin ... etc.

For columns that have only binary-values:

- Find the **indices** of all rows that have a zero as a value, and the **indices** of all rows that have a one as a value.

**My questions**:

1- Is there an efficient/good way to automatically detect the type of a column? I need this so I can automate the process and don't have to check the matrix manually and then do the preprocessing.

2- Suppose that I knew that column 0 has only real-values, then I know how to get the indices of the rows like this: `np.nonzero(X[:,0]>0.1)`, however this is not what I need because it's missing the second condition i.e something like this: `np.nonzero(X[:,0]<0 and X[:,0]<0.2)` of course this doesn't work, so I don't know to incorporate the second condition here.

**Edit1:**

this is how I solved the second question:

```
X = np.random.randn(8,3)

bins = [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]
bins = np.array(bins)

col = X[:,0] #here I detect that the first column is real-valued.

binplace = np.digitize(col, bins) #each element in binplace is the index of the bin that this element falls into.

for bin in xrange(bins.size):
    elements_inds = np.where(binplace==bin)[0]
```

**Edit2:**

Here is a little *dirty hack* to try to detect the type of the columns:

```
#To detect which cols are which type
n_rows = X.shape[0]

#check if col0 is binary or not

v=(X[:,0] == 1)

num_ones = np.where(v)[0].size

v=(X[:,0] == 0)

num_zeros = np.where(v)[0].size

total_size = num_ones + num_zeros


if n_rows == total_size:
    print 'this is a binary column'
else:
    print 'this is a real-valued column'
```

Comment: Have you checked the `dtype` property?

Comment: If I understand, you're saying that `X` is a floating point array, but that some of the columns contain only 0.0 or 1.0, and you want to find the indices of these columns. Is that correct?

Comment: @ali_m yup that is true

Answer (score 0):

First, let's make some example data:

```
x = np.random.randn(5, 5)
# we threshold columns 1 and 3 so that they're either 0 or 1
x[:, [1, 3]] = x[:, [1, 3]] > 0

print x
# [[ 1.65585901  1.         -0.05846647  0.          0.19013289]
#  [-0.60492332  0.         -0.23341666  1.         -0.66814078]
#  [-0.60287221  0.         -0.99057634  0.          0.45945837]
#  [ 0.33393323  0.          0.23511501  1.          0.62303913]
#  [-0.66428594  1.         -0.35667229  0.          1.07982347]]
```

Now you basically want to find columns where all of the entries are either very close to 0 or very close to 1.

You do something like this:

```
bool_cols = np.all(np.logical_or(np.isclose(x, 0), np.isclose(x, 1)), axis=0)
print bool_cols
# [False  True False  True False]
```

To unpack that line:

- [`np.isclose(x, val)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) tests whether each of the elements in `x` is within some fine tolerance of `val`, and returns a boolean array that is `True` wherever this is the case. Note that [you should never test for exact equality of floating point values](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/Comparing%20floating%20point%20numbers.htm), e.g. using `==`.
- [`np.logical_or(A, B)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html) returns a boolean array that is the same size as `A` and `B`, and is `True` where either `A` or `B` is `True`.
- [`np.all(X, axis=0)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) tests whether `X` is `True` across all rows (i.e. for each column).

You could use the set of boolean indices directly, e.g. `x[:, bool_cols]`, or you could return the indices of the boolean columns using `np.where`.

If some of your columns are integer values, you could use the `%` (modulo) operator to find columns where the remainder from division by 1 is very small, e.g:

```
int_cols = np.all(np.isclose(x % 1, 0), axis=0)
```

However, these indices would also include any boolean columns.